# Powershell Out-GridView from JSON file

Tags: json, powershell, pipeline

I want to load a JSON file and show it in a powershell GridView. I was hoping this would work:

```
'[{"a":1,"b":2},{"a":3,"b":4},{"a":5,"b":6}]' | ConvertFrom-Json | Out-GridView
```

But that just shows me this unhelpful view: [image: ogv output]
How can I transform the list into something the grid view understands?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
('[{"a":1,"b":2},{"a":3,"b":4},{"a":5,"b":6}]' | ConvertFrom-Json) | Out-GridView

# or

$converted = '[{"a":1,"b":2},{"a":3,"b":4},{"a":5,"b":6}]' | ConvertFrom-Json 
$converted | Out-GridView
```

This is a peculiarity of `ConvertFrom-Json` and anything that uses it implicitly (like `Invoke-RestMethod`). It doesn't seem to pass objects along the pipeline as you would expect, so you must complete the pipeline to get the objects, and then use them afterwards.

One way to do that is to assign it to a variable, another way is to wrap it in parentheses `( )`.

I am not certain why this is the case, but I imagine it's an implementation detail about what it does internally and how it returns its objects.

---

I was trying to see if I could dig more into this, using `ForEach-Object` to see what's going wrong, but instead it actually just worked, so here's another way to  get it working, but in a single pipeline (by using a superfluous `ForEach-Object`):

```
'[{"a":1,"b":2},{"a":3,"b":4},{"a":5,"b":6}]' | ConvertFrom-Json | ForEach-Object { $_ } | Out-GridView

# non-scrolling
'[{"a":1,"b":2},{"a":3,"b":4},{"a":5,"b":6}]' | ConvertFrom-Json | % { $_ } | ogv
```

Comment: HI, I tried your solution, I get details from docker system info --format '{{json .}}' | ConvertFrom-Json | ForEach-Object { $_ } | Out-GridView but still displays only 1 line for all values (every field/value is a column), so I need it to be each in one row but it is not working